# Append function of linked list doesn't work - C

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

Basically, I am trying to insert a node into the linked list via the append function I'm writing. Although in the function, it appears that my node header has the same value of the address of my first node, after the function closes it turns back to null.

This is my append function:

```
void append(node* header, node newNode) {
    
    //check if header is NULL
    //if not add first value

    if (header == NULL) {
        header = &newNode;
        printf("List val: %p\n", header);
        printf("node address: %p\n\n", &newNode);
    }
    
    else {
        
        //find last node
        node* tmp = header;
        while (tmp -> next != NULL) {
            tmp = tmp -> next;
        }
        
        // inser lastnode.next to be address of new node
        tmp -> next = &newNode;
    }
}
```

And then in main, I created a header and node and call this function, and ask to print value of list and address of node a:

```
node* list = NULL;
node a = {1, NULL};
append(list, a);
printf("%p\n", list);
printf("%p\n", &a);
```

The output is:

List val: 000000b6779ff900
node address: 000000b6779ff900

0000000000000000
000000b6779ff970

So for some reason, the value of the node* list after the function is still NULL. Still new to this pointer thing, so I am currently having trouble understanding where I am wrong.

Edit: Community bot tells me to provide enough code, so I bet it's something about the node type?

```
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node* next;
} node;
```

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your function does not modify the global `list`, as it is passed by value. Also you are passing `newNode` by value, then taking it's address, which is an address of a *local* variable

Comment: @Eugene Sh. So should I do `void append(node** header, node* newNode)` and change all `header` into `*header`, `&newNode` into `newNode`?

Comment: @TommyVo That would be a step to the right direction.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems in your code:

1. Your `list` variable isn't getting updated. You are passing the value of the `list` (call by value) to the function. If you want to reflect the changes made to the value, you need to update it in the main function. So, drop the return type of append function from `void` to `node*` or make `list` global (the former is preferred).
2. You are passing the value of the `node` as an argument to `append` and accessing its address in the function. This address isn't the address provided to the node at `main`; rather, it is the address provided to it when `append` is called. So, pass `&a` instead of `a`.

Here is some code I wrote to help you out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} node;

node* append(node* header, node* new_node){
    if(header == NULL){
        header = new_node;
        return header;
    }

    node* temp = header;
    while(temp -> next != NULL){
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    temp -> next = new_node;
    return header;
}

int main(void){
    node* list = NULL; // header
    
    // first node
    node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node -> data = 1;
    new_node -> next = NULL;

    // second node
    node* new_node2 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node2 -> data = 2;
    new_node2 -> next = NULL;

    // third node
    node* new_node3 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node3 -> data = 3;
    new_node3 -> next = NULL;

    // fourth node
    node a = {4, NULL}; // your style :)

    // the above can be squeezed to one 'create' function

    list = append(list, new_node);  // the if condition
    list = append(list, new_node2); // the else condition
    list = append(list, new_node3); // the else condition
    list = append(list, &a);

    printf("%d\n", list -> data);
    printf("new_node: %p\n", new_node);
    printf("%d\n", list -> next -> data);
    printf("new_node2: %p\n", new_node2);
    printf("%d\n", list -> next -> next ->  data);
    printf("new_node3: %p\n", new_node3);
    printf("%d\n", list -> next -> next -> next -> data);
    printf("a: %p\n", &a);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal behavior. Actually you are passing a pointer `header` to the function. When you assign it to a value, you only change the local reference..

You may rather want to pass a pointer to the pointer, expressed as `struct node **header` and then set it with `*header = newNode`.